# Retrieving row data from SQLite Db based on Unique Identifier

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have implemented an SQLite DB into my app and i am trying to write functions that will retrieve the data in a row associated with the unique identifier. I have tried a lot of stackoverflow answers and none seem to be working in my situation.

I have a database helper class where i have created the database through code and am writing the functions. See code below:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TrackerNew.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tracker_new_table";
public static final String COL_2 = "LINETYPE";
public static final String COL_3 = "PACKAGETYPE";
public static final String COL_4 = "QUANTITY";
public static final String COL_5 = "DURATION";
public static final String COL_6 = "STARTTIME";
public static final String COL_7 = "ENDTIME";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1); }


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +"  (LINETYPE TEXT PRIMARY KEY,PACKAGETYPE TEXT,QUANTITY TEXT,DURATION TEXT,STARTTIME TEXT,ENDTIME TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String linetype, String packagetype, String quantity, String duration, String starttime, String endtime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,linetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,packagetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,duration);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,starttime);
    contentValues.put(COL_7,endtime);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

//FUNCTIONS TO GET DATA BY ROW

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2="S1");
    return res;
}

public Cursor getProgressBar2() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2="S2");
    return res;
}
```

}

If you can see my functions at the bottom of my code i am trying to write raw queries to get the data by ID( S1,S2 Etc.)

Can anyone help me out with the code inside these functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to create a string using:-

```
"select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2="S1"
```

This will not compile because you have misplaced the **=** and overwritten or omitted the **+** concatenation. I believe that you should have (see later):-

```
"select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2  + "=S1"
```

(**+** added after COL_2 and **=** moved inside the quotes.

However I then believe that this would fail because you have omitted spaces before and after **where**, so the above would then resolve to:-

> select * from tracker_new_tablewhereLINETYPE = S1

With spaces around **where** as per :-

```
"select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_2  + "=S1"
```

It will then resolve to :-

> select * from tracker_new_table where LINETYPE=S1

However, SQLite will then fail as S1 is not numeric and thus must be in quotes, so you need to actually code :-

**`"select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_2  + "='S1'"`**

However coding :-

```
public Cursor getProgressBar1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2="S1");
    return res;
}
```

Will then fail as the Cursor `query` method expects at least 7 parameters, as per :-

> `query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
>   selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)`
>
> Query the given table, returning a Cursor over the result set.
>   [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

So to use the `query method` the parameters would be:-

- 1) The name of the table to be queried so `db.query(TABLE_NAME ......`
- 2) A string array of the column names to extract, null means all and equates to *, so `db.query(TABLE_NAME,null ......`
- 3) The selection string (SELECT clause) (which can include placeholders i.e **?** as per 4th parameter). Without place holders `db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "='S1'"`, or with a placeholder (generally considered the preferred method), `db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?" ......`
- 4) The values to replace the placeholder(s) on a use once basis. So for a single place holder `new String[]{"S1"}` could be used, so the code now becomes `db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S1"} ......`
- 5) A GROUP BY clause, null if not using one.
- 6) A HAVING clause, null if not using one.
- 7) An ORDER BY clause, null it not using one.

(Note *clauses do not have the respective KEYWORDS the query method inserts them it also handles escaping/quoting*)

The full query could/should be:-

```
Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S1"},null,null,null);
```

#### Finally

And the **`ProgressBar1`** method would be:-

```
public Cursor getProgressBar1() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{"S1"},null,null,null);
    return res;
}
```

---

#### Edit after comment

As you want to also search for "S2" and "S3" then perhaps a single method could cope e.g.

```
public Cursor getProgressBar(String linetype) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{linetype},null,null,null);
    return res;
}
```

Then for progress bar 1 you could use:-

```
    Cursor progressbar1 = getProgressbar("S1");
```

for progress bar 2

```
    Cursor progressbar2 = getProgressbar("S2");
```

etc

You could also shorten the `getProgressBar` method to :-

```
public Cursor getProgressBar(String linetype) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{linetype},null,null,null);
}
```

or even :-

```
public Cursor getProgressBar(String linetype) {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,COL_2 + "=?",new String[]{linetype},null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks @MikeT!

Comment: Just a question on that... if I have methods progressbar2, 3 etc. where I will be searching for the row with S2, S3. is the {"S1"} part where I would change this to S2,3?

Comment: yep basically exactly the same except new String[]{"S2"}. However, I've edited the answer for what could be a better way.

Comment: yes that makes it a lot more efficient! thanks again :)

Comment: Hi @MikeT you still there? have a few more questions if you dont mind :)

Comment: @AaronRogers3 Was in bed.

Comment: I am trying to use these data retrieval functions that you give me and display each column data of a row in textviews. How can I separate each "cell" or column data of each row in order to display them separately? thought id ask as you were great help

Comment: @AaronRogers3 assuming the above query and just the 1 row. if (res.moveToFirst) { TextViewS1.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("S1")); TextViewS2.settext(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("S2"))) etc } Note not checked so there could be typos.

Comment: and if the textviews that I'm targeting are on a different activity, how can I trigger them?

Comment: Just to give u an example. S1 is the name of a production line. so say I also have a column called package type in the next column would the code be:    if (res.moveToFirst) { TextViewPackagetype.setText(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Packagetype"));??

Comment: Rather than target them (unless using fragments) then get the Cursor and set the TextViews in both the activities `onCreate` and `onResume` methods. Fragments is a lot harder to explain as comments and I'm not that familiar with them.

Comment: @AaronRogers3 you'll be tutoring me tomorrow :) i.e. yep.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to modify this query:

```
Cursor res = db.query("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + "where" + COL_2="S1");
```

to:

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_2 + " = ?", new String[] {"S1"});
```

and in getProgressBar2() method too. For more info look to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: that is exactly the same as what i have?

Comment: it is saying "variable expected"?

Comment: "where" and " where " not the same

Comment: also modify: + COL_2="S1" to: + COL_2 + "=S1"

Comment: Still saying variable expected and showing red line under the query

Comment: Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+ TABLE_NAME + " where " + COL_2 + " = ?", new String[] {"S1"});